# Can we go ahead with Coinbase or CoineBase-Pro?

Tags: coinbase-api

We are referring coinbase pro sandbox API currently, and its testing environment. Do we need to purchase coinbase pro? We are trying to develop an application that is related to cryptocurrency. Also, we are going to develop
applications in .Net technology and for that, we are using Coinbase-Pro Sandbox for selling the ETH.
So we just want to know that either we will go ahead with Coinbase or CoineBase-Pro?

Comment: I've used the free PHP API for a year to build a database of prices collected every 3 minutes for trend analysis. Free if fine for this. Although I haven't tried my research suggested trading/swapping is clunky with free version; you have to do the composite trades separately, which opens you up to potential pitfalls of delays etc. If the Pro version allows you to do the swaps via a single API call then that saves complexity and potential errors.

Comment: @TenG PRO doesn't do swaps, you buy/sell from other traders. You might have a traded pair like btc-eth, but you want to "swap" to something that doesn't have a traded pair you would have to do something like sell eth-usdt and buy dot-usdt.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what "free" version @TenG is talking about. Both of the APIs are free. Pro is actually less than coinbase in fees, you just pay the transaction fee of .5% until you earn the next fee tier. I've been using the PRO API for almost a year now with no issues.

As for which to use, that's entirely up to you and your use case.

Comment: I just want to know that can I use coinbase pro "sandbox" api in project development for selling ETH or also I want to know that if coinbase pro sandbox api is use for project development. Can I leverage this in coinbase also or not?

Comment: @DhrutiPatel `Do we need to purchase coinbase pro?` No. `So we just want to know that either we will go ahead with Coinbase or CoineBase-Pro?` if you're asking specifically about a coinbase sandbox environment I don't think the is one. Not that I could find anyway but I only use the coinbase pro api.